# Time/Date not converting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have received raw data that has a column of data with the following date and time stamp format:

Mar 31 2014 3:38AM

The format of the cells are not consistent as some have single spaces and others have double or triple spaces in them between characters.  So I generated a formula to give me single spaces.  However when I use the "dateValue" or "TimeValue" to convert the cell to a value I can use (add dates / times) I'm getting a #value ref.

I have read a number of answers on this and tried a few tips but I can't get it working.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe because `Mar 31 2014 3:38AM` is not a proper DATE in Excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use an UDF to achieve this with custom formatted dates. Open VBE and add a standard module. Copy and paste those two functions to the module

```
Function MyDateValue(r As Range) As String
    MyDateValue = DateValue(CDate(r))
End Function

Function MyTimeValue(r As Range) As String
    MyTimeValue = TimeValue(CDate(r))
End Function
```

Now go back to your spreadsheet and enter

`=MyDateValue(A1)`

and

`=MyTimeValue(A1)`

you should be getting the correct values

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a comma to the date string, that works for me when I reproduce your issue.

```
Mar 31, 2014 3:38AM
```

I used a formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B7," 2014",", 2014")
```

Comment: Thank you for comment and support offered.